# Remove focus on editable jtable cell

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, tablecelleditor

When double click on editable cell of jtable it shown as here.

[image: follow]

what i need is if user click mouse outside table of press a button before entering the value then existing value should be auto entered and output should be shown as follow.

[image: after]

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. for DefaultTableModel works by default `myJTable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE)`;
2. override `stopCellEditing()`

   a) `public boolean stopCellEditing()`

   b) `myJTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();`

   c) `myJTable.getCellEditor(row, col).stopCellEditing();`

Comment: thanks mKorbel. I just found this link also have solution releated to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652942/can-a-jtable-save-data-whenever-a-cell-loses-focus

Comment: before any questions about JTable search for answers by (@camickr) or (@kleopatra), then you'll 100pct of success :-)

Comment: yeah...good point. Seems It's worth than couple of hours googling.