# Want to deselect table cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

In a JTable, if I type a value in table cell and when I click the button to print the value of that cell. But I input a value and immediately click the button it does not print. If I press enter after the input a value in cell and click on the button, now it prints well. How can I prevent this in my table ?

Comment: no idea what do you talking about, maybe is one, two mindreaders around, otherwise for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JTable and JButton

Answer (score 3):

> In a JTable, if I type a value in table cell and when I click the
>   button to prints the value of that cell. But I input a value and
>   immediately click the button it's not print. If I press enter after
>   the input a value in cell and click on the button, now it's print
>   well. How can I prevent this in my table ?

my shots in the dark

- set `myTable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);` for `DefaultCellEditor`

  or
- override `public boolean stopCellEditing() {` for any custom editors types e.g. `XxxCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {`

Comment: +1 for `"terminateEditOnFocusLost"`; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12826753/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12884697/230513).