# get edited value of cell in JTable after a button clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to get the edited value of a cell in my JTable when i click the button named "save"?

Comment: `table.getValueAt(row, column);`.

Comment: thanks..I tried it, but didn't work

Comment: What it returned? Try `String value = table.getValueAt(row, column).toString();`

Comment: it returned old value of column. when I edit column ,it didn't returned new value

Answer (score 2):

New value can be get from the `DefaultCellEditor`.

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (table.getCellEditor() != null) {
                DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = (DefaultCellEditor) table.getCellEditor();
                String value = ((JTextField) cellEditor.getComponent()).getText();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Action listener of your button.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't create a Action listener and I don't understand how to do that.I'm very new to this

Comment: My sample adding an action listener. Please try it.

Comment: Is it still returns the old value?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652942/can-a-jtable-save-data-whenever-a-cell-loses-focus) solution will be sufficient for you:

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

It saves all table data not only when "save" button is clicked, but also in other cases of focus change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should help you : [table cell listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/)