# in JTable the cell is editing after its losing the focus also

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using JTextField as a DefaultCellEditor for the all column of the JTable.

When I edit a cell and press Enter then the focus go to the next cell. But when I write in this cell then the values are inserted into the previous cell. But I want that this value should be entered into the focused cell how to do that you can see the snapshot

[image: here]

here is the code

```
package abc;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class VoucherDialog extends JDialog {
    JPanel contentPane;
    JLabel jl1,jl2,jl3;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    String[] column_headers= {"SN","REF","DATE","PARTICULARS","AMOUNT",};
    String[][] items= {};
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    TableModel tm;

    ResultSet rs=null;
    String c1,c2;
    int rowz,col;
    JTextField snField,dateField,particularField,refField;
    JFormattedTextField amountField;
    JComboBox<String> ref_Cb;

    JPopupMenu popup;
    NumberFormat amountFormat;
    private double amount = 100000;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            VoucherDialog dialog = new VoucherDialog();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     * @throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException 
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws InstantiationException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws ParseException 
     */
    public VoucherDialog() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException,NumberFormatException, ParseException
    {
        contentPane=new JPanel();
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //setBounds(100, 100, 571, 322);
        setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            ActionListener a=new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    dispose(); 
                }   
            };
            this.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(a,KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE,0),JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1, 0, 0));

        jl1=new JLabel();
        jl1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jl1.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.BOLD, 16));
        jl1.setText(c1);
        panel.add(jl1);

        jl2=new JLabel();
        jl2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jl2.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        jl2.setText(c2);
        panel.add(jl2);

        jl3=new JLabel();
        jl3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jl3.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        jl3.setText("**Product Master** ");
        panel.add(jl3);


        model=new DefaultTableModel(items,column_headers)
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
            {
                if(column == 0 )
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(model){
            //      private boolean inLayout;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) 
            {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                if (isRowSelected(row)) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    c.setBackground(Color.white);
                    c.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }
                return c;
            }

        };

        table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    // Select the current cell
                    rowz = table.getSelectedRow();
                    col = table.getSelectedColumn();
                    int totalrows=table.getRowCount();
                    if((rowz+1)==totalrows)
                    {
                        model.addRow(new Object[] {"","","","",""});
                    }
                    //table.repaint(); 
                } 


                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT)
                {
                    int row=table.getSelectedRow();
                    model.insertRow(row,new Object[] {"1","","","",""} );

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    // Select the current cell
                    rowz = table.getSelectedRow();
                    col = table.getSelectedColumn();

                    int totalrows=table.getRowCount();

                    if((rowz+1)==totalrows)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<table.getColumnCount();i++)
                        { 
                            int x=0;
                            if(table.getSelectedRow()>0)
                            {
                                x=Integer.valueOf(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow()-1,0).toString());
                                x=x+1;
                            }
                            else
                                x=0;
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }



        });


        //to make the Border at selected cell
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
        {
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus,int row,int column)
            {
                super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); 
                //setBorder(noFocusBorder);
                if (hasFocus)
                {
                    setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
                    // to scrolling JTable automatically to the Bottom
                    scrollToVisible(table,table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn());

                }
                return this;

            }
        });


        table.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
        table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);



        // to work the enter key like the tab
        InputMap im = table.getInputMap();
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Action.NextCell");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "Action.NextCell");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "Action.NextCell");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "Action.PreviousCell");

        ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
        am.put("Action.NextCell", new NextCellActioin(table));
        am.put("Action.PreviousCell", new PreviousCellAction(table));

        //to remove the vertical lines of the Table Header
        for(int i = 0; i <column_headers.length; i++)
        {
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            column.setHeaderRenderer(new HeaderRenderer());
        }  

        table.setRowHeight(25);
        //table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
        table.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.BOLD, 16));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMinWidth(130);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(130);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMinWidth(250);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(250);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMinWidth(250);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(250);


        TableColumn snColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        snField=new JTextField();
        snField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        snField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        snColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(snField));


        TableColumn refColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        refField=new JFormattedTextField();
        refField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        refField.setEditable(true);
        refField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        refColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(refField)); 

        TableColumn dateColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        JFormattedTextField dateTextField = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("##/##/####"));
        dateTextField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        dateTextField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        dateColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(dateTextField));

        TableColumn particularColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        particularField=new JTextField();
        particularField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        particularField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        particularColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(particularField));

        TableColumn amountColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
        //amountField=new JFormattedTextField(createAmountFormatter());
        amountField=new JFormattedTextField(amountFormat);
        amountField.setValue(amount);

        //amountField.addFocusListener(l);
        amountField.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        amountField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        //amountField.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 14));
        amountColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(amountField));

        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(); 
        scrollPane.setViewportBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(255, 0, 0)));
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants. HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants. VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        scrollPane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );


        for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
        {

            model.addRow(new Object[] {"1","","","",""});
            table.setValueAt(i+1, i,0);
        }

        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }




    // to scrolling JTable automatically to the Bottom
    public static  void scrollToVisible(final JTable table, final int rowIndex, final int vColIndex) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(rowIndex, vColIndex, false));
            }
        });
    }




    class NextCellActioin extends AbstractAction {

        private JTable table;

        public NextCellActioin(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

            int colCount = table.getColumnCount();
            int rowCount = table.getRowCount();

            int x;
            System.out.println("NExt");
            do
            {
                col++;
                if (col >= colCount) {
                    col = 0;
                    row++;
                }

                if (row >= rowCount) {
                    row = 0;
                }
                TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col);
                x=column.getWidth();
                if(x!=0)
                    col--;
                //else if(x==0)
                //setDefaultValue(col);
            }while(x==0); 
            col++;
            if (col >= colCount) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }

            if (row >= rowCount) {
                row = 0;
            }

            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
            table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(col, col);
        }

    }

    class PreviousCellAction extends AbstractAction {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JTable table;

        public PreviousCellAction(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

            int colCount = table.getColumnCount();
            int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
            System.out.println("Previous");

            int x;
            do
            {
                col--;
                System.out.println("3"+col);
                if (col<0)
                {
                    col =colCount-1;
                    row--;

                    System.out.println("1"+col);
                }
                if (row<0) 
                {
                    row =rowCount-1;

                }
                x = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getWidth();
                //x=column.getWidth();
                if(x!=0)
                    col++;
                //else if(x==0)
                System.out.println("2"+x);
                //setDefaultValue(col);
            }while(x==0); 
            col--;

            if (col<0)
            {
                /*if (row==0) 
                {
                  row =rowCount;  
                }
                else*/
                System.out.println("2"+col);
                col =colCount-1;
                row--;
                System.out.println("3"+col);

            }

            if (row<0) 
            {
                row =rowCount-1;

            }

            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
            table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(col, col);
        }

    }
}

//this class used to hide the tableHeader
class HeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean hasFocus,
            boolean isSelected,
            int row,
            int col)
    {

        setText(value.toString());
        setFont(new Font("Lucida Console", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you to solve your problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652942/can-a-jtable-save-data-whenever-a-cell-loses-focus)

Comment: The problem is your custom code, not the JTable. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working examples.

Comment: i also paste the code here to show the problem clearly . now can anyone help me in this.